# LaTex symbol command for fibre bundle

Tags: symbols

Do you know the LaTeX command to compose the following letter B taken from "The topology of fiber bundle" by N. Steenrod?

[image]

Comment: `\mathcal{B}` or `\mathscr{B}` (`mathrsfs` package), the look will depend on the fonts used.

Comment: Your B it is similar to the B of mtc (Mathtime Pro 2 Curly script), a package not fully free in LaTeX. There is only the lite version. You can see to page six to the link https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mathalpha/doc/mathalpha-doc.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

As @Sebastiano mentions in the comments, the actual character most likely comes from a commercial font not freely available. But I don't think Steenrod uses the font for any other character, so here is a mockup of a replacement using the `calligraphy` tikz library.

I set the height of the new symbol to be `1.43ex`, which is about the same height as a lowercase `t`. That's how it looks in my copy of the book. You can adjust the thickness of the character by changing the `scale=.5`. Higher value gives you a thinner character; lower value is thicker.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}

\newcommand{\BB}{\resizebox{!}{1.43ex}{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.5,baseline]
\calligraphy[copperplate] (0,.99) .. controls +(-.4,0) and +(.7,0) .. (-.3,0) [this stroke style={heavy}]
+(0,0) .. controls +(-.4,0) and +(-.5,0) .. (-.1,1) [this stroke style={light,taper=none}]
+(0,0) .. controls +(.6,0) and +(.5,0) .. (0,.53) [this stroke style={heavy}]
+(.2,.02) .. controls +(.5,-.2) and +(.25,-.3) .. (.05,.1) [this stroke style={heavy}];
\end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{document}

\paragraph{Mappings of bundles.} Let $\BB$ and $\BB'$ be two coordinate bundles having the same fibre and the same group.
By a \emph{map} $h\colon\BB\to\BB'$ is meant a continuous map $h\colon B\to B'$ having the following properties

\end{document}
```